# How to run sample project in IOS device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am working on Audio capture related task, I have downloaded speak here sample code from Apple site, I just want to run and debug about its functionality, when I am trying in my device, it is saying invalid provision certificate, I know what is provisional certificate, we registered for our application. My question is how to run sample projects in device. Is there any way?

please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install application on any iOS device you have to have a developer account and it is not free.

Comment: I have account, but it is registered with my product, our product is running fine on my device, I'm trying to run some sample code, it is not allowing...

Comment: Check the bundle ID and Code Sign identity of the test project.

Comment: Depends on you. If you use it only for learning then its alright.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to this website

`http://jailcoder.com/`

What this does program does is patch SDKSettings.plist inside of Xcode and also patches your project (just adds a run script) and install on your device with fake provisions certificate. This is all fully reversible. You will need to have your device jailbroken with `appsync` installed.

Then you can just build for device and it'll run it on your device instead of the simulator.

Comment: Sorry dude, Is any other way do it legally.

Comment: this is not illegal everything is reversible even the jailbreak it is just for testing purposes anyways but make sure you have the bundle identifier correct in your certificate and in your project and check Targets Build Settings and check the correct certificate is selected

Answer (score 1):

To install application for development or distribution on iOS device you have to "Enroll" or "BUY" to **Apple's** Developer program or Enterprise program.

1. **Developer Program** 
      Its have Developer certificate as well Distribution certificate but its follows UUID means device ID to install on device.
2. **Enterprise program** 
      Its have Developer certificate as well Distribution certificate but UUID means device ID is optional for **in-House** distribution provision profile to install on device so you can install on any device.